# Error from Android NDK: Could not extract package's data directory. Are you sure that your installed application is debuggable?

Tags: mac, android, debug

I'm using Eclipse to debug my Android app which has a C native code.

When I plug in my Nexsus4 the NDK external debugging tool works.

When I plug my Galaxy Note2 it throws the following error when trying to attach to the device:

```
Android NDK installation path: /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/android-ndk-r8b
Using specific adb command: /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/sdk/platform-tools/adb
ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
Using ADB flags: 
Using auto-detected project path: .
Found package name: com.myPack
ABIs targetted by application: armeabi
Device API Level: 18
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
Compatible device ABI: armeabi
Using gdb setup init: ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Using toolchain prefix: /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi
Found debuggable flag: true
Found device gdbserver: /data/data/com.myPack/lib/gdbserver
ERROR: Could not extract package's data directory. Are you sure that
       your installed application is debuggable?
```

I have enabled developers options
and allowed device debugging via USB.

It doesn't work for my Samsung Galaxy Note2 (Android 4.3) but works for Nexsus4 (4.2).

I think this is a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373),
but how do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a [look at comment #29](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373#c29)?

> For NDK r9:
>
> Find this line in ndk-gdb:
>
> ```
> run adb_cmd shell run-as $PACKAGE_NAME lib/gdbserver +$DEBUG_SOCKET --attach $PID &
> ```
>
> replace it with these 4 lines (assuming you have $NDK defined, and
>   assuming your target device is ARM):
>
> ```
> run adb_cmd forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039 run adb_cmd remount run adb_cmd
> push $NDK/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver /system/bin/gdbserver.temp
> run adb_cmd shell /system/bin/gdbserver.temp --attach :5039 $PID &
> ```
>
> I am working from memory above, didn't actually test exactly what I've
>   written just now, so I apologize for any mistakes, but that is the
>   general idea.
>
> Again, this requires rooted device.

Comment: no. my device is not rooted. and i'm using NDK r8b

Comment: also it used to work on the same device on 4.2